# jQuery .data not working

Tags: jquery

So, essentially I have set up a page that will allow a user to click on an anchor, and when they do, a jQuery function should display new content in a defined div using jQuery .html. It also should be dynamically pulling that content from custom data attributes, however it isn't working. What am I doing wrong? Here's the HTML.

```
<section id="about">

<div class="content-container"> 

<h2 class="title"><span>About</span> the Film</h2><!-- / .title -->

<nav id="crew-nav">
<ul id="crew-list">

  <li class="jesse" data-first="Jesse" data-last="Winton" data-bio="JESSE WINTON is ultra mega cool beans." data-image="http://development.targetedthemovie.com/img/crew/jesse-winton-background.jpg">
    <a href="#">Jesse Winton<br>
      <span>Director/Writer</span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="matt" data-first="Matt" data-last="Blick" data-bio="MATT BLICK is an awesome person when you pretend he doesn't exist." data-image="http://development.targetedthemovie.com/img/crew/matt-blick-background.jpg">
    <a href="#">Matt Blick<br>
      <span>Director of Photography</span>
    </a>
  </li>

</ul><!-- / #crew-list -->
</nav><!-- / #crew-nav -->

<div class="top-mask"></div><!-- / .top-mask -->

<article id="about-content" class="content">

<article> 
<h4 class="first-name"></h4><!-- / .first-name -->
<h3 class="last-name"></h3><!-- / .last-name -->

Wintons Motion Pictures brings you a new, hard-hitting documentary film by Jesse Winton. TARGETED will be examining one of the key issues of the day, gun control, and will take you on a fast-paced journey, following 19 year-old director Jesse Winton as he travels across the world, and goes back to the historical roots of the gun-control agenda, exposing it, and bringing out the dark truth behind gun control. TARGETED will creatively answer the increasingly tough questions regarding the issue, as well as giving us a plan that will help to mobilize freedom-loving Americans to defend the rights and liberties that have been granted to us. Coming 2014.
</article>   

</article><!-- / #about-content -->

<div class="bottom-mask"></div><!-- / .bottom-mask -->

</div><!-- / .content-container -->

</section><!-- / #about -->
```

And here's the jQuery

JUST EDITED THIS TO CLARIFY. THE data-bio SHOULD BE LOADED IN THROUGH THE VARIABLE

```
var bio = $(this).data('bio');

$('.jesse').live('click', function() {
$('#about').css('background-image','url('+$img+')');
$('#about-content article').html(bio);
});

$('.matt').live('click', function() {
  $('#about').css('background-image','url('+$img+')');
  $('#about-content article').html(bio);
});
```

So, as you can see in the HTML, I have the bio content stored in custom data attributes, and in the jQuery, when you click on the list item, the new content should be loaded into the #about div, but it won't do it. Anyone see the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the context of your code? What does `this` refer to? Also, you are setting the any HTML content, you are only *getting* it. Did you read the documentation? http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2. This [jQuery tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/) might help as well.

Comment: Are you running the JavaScript in a ready handler, like `$(function() { /* your code */ }) or `$(document).ready(function() { /* your code */ })`?

Comment: You're not setting the html of #about... it needs a parameter. http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: @FelixKling I just made an edit. 'this' refers to the list-item that's been clicked.

Comment: @sachleen just made an edit for that.

Comment: @Jacob I'm not, but the rest of the jQuery that I have on that page is working just fine. It's only ever been the data attribute.

Comment: So the code runs inside an event handler? Why are you binding event handlers inside another event handler then?

Comment: @FelixKling could you clarify? I'm not a super in-depth jQuery developer...

Comment: What is this code `var $this = $(this);
var bio = $(this).data('bio');` in?  We need to see what that is in so we know what the value of `this` is.

Comment: If your code is like `$('li').click(function() { var $this = $(this); ... });`, then yes, `this` would refer to the clicked list item. But you would bind event handlers (with `.live`) to elements as well, which is weird. If this code is not inside a handler, then `this` does refer to the clicked element (and I'd wonder why you think it does).

Comment: @FelixKling Like I said, I'm not super skilled in jQuery... how should it be written, I'm here to learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `.live` is deprecated and I don't think you need to use event delegation here anyway.

If you want `this` to refer to the clicked list element, i.e. either `.jesse` or `.matt`, you have put those assignments **inside** the event handlers:

```
$('.jesse').click('click', function() {
   var bio = $(this).data('bio');
   $('#about').css('background-image','url('+$img+')');
   $('#about-content article').html(bio);
});

$('.matt').click('click', function() {
  var bio = $(this).data('bio');
  $('#about').css('background-image','url('+$img+')');
  $('#about-content article').html(bio);
});
```

and of course this can be unified to

```
$('#crew-list > li').on('click', function() {
    var bio = $(this).data('bio');
    $('#about').css('background-image','url('+$img+')');
    $('#about-content article').html(bio);
});
```

I don't know where `$img` comes from, but I just assume it's a string containing a URL.

I recommend to read the [jQuery tutorial about event handling](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/).